# Laptop and 2 monitors

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I currently have have the following configuration [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17604288/Setup.jpg]

Both monitors can be detected but for some reason I can't get them to show separate things (ie. they are just a clone of one another).

The setup I want to achieve is to have a display that extends across both monitors. Tried using the Display function to extend, but it just extends across the monitor and the laptop. (ie. both monitor 1 and monitor 2 shows exactly the same thing, while the other screen that is being extended into is the laptop).

I have tried to update my Nvidia and Intel drivers already but to no avail. I am on Windows 10.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: While the docking station may have multiple video output connections, they almost certainly connect internally to the same video output in the laptop. Your display setup is probably showing you two monitors (the laptop's built-in one and a single external).  There are external video adapters that connect via USB and support multiple external monitors; I suspect that's what you'll need.

Comment: I suppose you mean an HDMI to VGA adapter, not VGA to HDMI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the [product specification of your docking station](http://j5create.com/our-products/docking-stations/jud530.html), it doesn't support two separate *external* monitors, just notebook monitor plus 1 external attached to the dock.

[image]

[j5create customer service on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx3IXX2NQZY0ONM/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B008KJTIGU) recommends to additionally buy their USB-to-VGA graphics adapter.